# Java Restful Services - Without JaxB

Tags: java, rest

I'm trying to write restful JSON webservices. I have implemented a few using CXF, however with CXF, JAX-RS the dependencies are bloating up the single page web application. Is there any easy way to compose restful services without any of JAX-RS and in particular without using JAXB based marshalling/unmarshalling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If CXF is providing more capabilities than you need, look into Jersey or Restlet, both of which may provide a library that specifically suits your needs.  Note that these are going to implement the JAX-RS specification.

Other guidance may depend on your environment.  You very well could write a servlet and handle the JSON yourself, see here for a discussion: [Reasons for not directly writing Servlets for creating a REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21947300/reasons-for-not-directly-write-servlets-for-creating-a-rest-api)

Comment: I have used CXF, I was very happy with it, now I use Restlet, which is lighter and easier and very powerful.