# REST using servlet

Tags: java, rest, servlets, gwt

I need to convert gwt methods to REST

I have a class that is using a gwt project which contains servelet method, now i am assign to convert that project to a rest...

I have class in gwt project that contain this

```
public class TOTPService extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Map<String, TOTPUser> totpUsersMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, TOTPUser>();

    private String TOTP_DB_PATH = "otpdb/TOTP.dat";
    private File TOTP_DB_FILE = null;
    private Gson gson = new Gson();

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        doPost(req, resp);
    }

    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        if(totpUsersMap.size() < 1){
            restoreHOTPData();
        }

        String method = request.getParameter("method");

        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
                "GET, PUT, POST, OPTIONS");
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
        response.addHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "86400");

        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        //df.gett
        String utcTime = df.format(new Date());
        System.out.println("--------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Request Received @ " + utcTime);
        if (method != null) {
            if (method.equals("REGISTER")) {
                String username = request.getParameter("username");
                Base32 base32 = new Base32();
                String secretKey = "";
                if(!totpUsersMap.containsKey(username)){
                    secretKey = GoogleAuthenticator.generateSecretKey();
                    System.out.println("\tNew User : [" + secretKey+ "]");
                    byte[] sharedSecret = base32.decode(secretKey);
                    TOTPUser totpUser = new TOTPUser();
                    totpUser.setUsername(username);
                    totpUser.setSecret(sharedSecret);
                    totpUsersMap.put(username, totpUser);
                    backupTOTPUser();
                }else{
                    if(!totpUsersMap.get(username).isSetup()){
                        secretKey = GoogleAuthenticator.generateSecretKey();
                        System.out.println("\tExisting User not finish in setup : [" + secretKey+ "]");
                        //e2 ung paglalagay ng user at pass
                        TOTPUser totpUser = totpUsersMap.get(username);
                        totpUser.setSecret(base32.decode(secretKey));

                        backupTOTPUser();
                    }else{
                        secretKey = base32.encodeAsString(totpUsersMap.get(username).getSecret());
                        System.out.println("\tExisting User finished setup : [" + secretKey+ "]");
                    }


                }

                String s = "otpauth://totp/" + username + "?secret="
                        + secretKey;

                ByteArrayOutputStream outs = QRCode.from(s).to(ImageType.PNG).stream();
                response.setContentType("image/png");
                response.setContentLength(outs.size());

                //e2 ung nag ooutput sa ram
                OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();

                outStream.write(outs.toByteArray());

                outStream.flush();
                outStream.close();

            }
}

NOW i am confused on how to convert this to REST

I create a class inside a rest project

that contains this

@Path("/OTPService")
public class OTPService {

    TOTPService totpService = new TOTPService();

    @GET
    @Path("/getOtp")
    public void getOtp() {
        // I dont know how will i call doGet and doPost from previous class
    }


}
```

I am new in REST i dont know if im doing it right.

Is there a way that i can use this servelet in my REST project? or do i need to change doGet or doPost method that will not use servelet?

Comment: this api will be called by another project using servlet the response is either an image or a string depending on the url given... currently this api is inside a gwt project

Comment: you can refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21947300/reasons-for-not-directly-write-servlets-for-creating-a-rest-api

Comment: Take a look at restyGWT: https://resty-gwt.github.io/ and jersey:https://jersey.java.net/ on the server side. Also, there is a nice example from David Chandler: https://turbomanage.wordpress.com/2014/07/23/painless-restjson-api-with-jersey-and-restygwt/

Answer (score 0):

To call a servlet to a rest 
1)You need to setup the servlet config on xml refer to the example

tput: select all tree view raw view

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
    <display-name>
        SSOOTPServiceREST
    </display-name>
    <servlet>
        <!--  Default servlet container config  -->
        <servlet-name>
            SSOOTPServiceREST
        </servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>
                jersey.config.server.provider.packages
            </param-name>
            <param-value>
                com.svi.sso.otpsvc.rest
            </param-value>
            <!--  Package where methods to be called by REST  -->
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <!--  servlets inside rest  -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>
            SSOOTPServiceREST
        </servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>
            /otprest/*
        </url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>
            GetOtp
        </servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            com.svi.sso.otpsvc.rest.OTPService
        </servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>
            GetOtp
        </servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>
            /otpservice
        </url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <!--  Default page to serve  -->
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>
            SSOOTPService.html
        </welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

2) call the servlet via REST
a)Declare necessary servlet parameters called by rest using @context
b) call the method that contains the servlet

```
@Context 
private ServletContext servletContext;
@Context 
private HttpServletRequest request;
@Context
private HttpServletResponse response;
@GET
@Path("/getotp")
public void getOtp(request,response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(request, response);//servelet to be called
    }
```